# dynamic selection country city using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote the code for dynamic selection country city like this way.The code running fine on Mozila, Chrome, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer *9*, but the dynamic selection of country city code is not working on Internet Explorer *8* and earlier versions.

```
<form method=post id="formname" name="formname" action=eaccountdb.php 
      enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="return Validate();">
  <table class="style2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table align="left" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td align="left">
              <label for="country">Country*</label>
      <?php
      $country = $_GET['country'];
      if ($country == null)
      {
          $data = mysql_query("select * from country where countryname !='$country'");
          echo "
                <select name='country' style='width:150px' id='country' 
                        onchange='show_country(this.value);'>
                  <option>Select Country</option>";
          while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
          {
              echo "<option>". $info['countryname']."</option>" ;
          }
          echo "</select>";
      }
      ...
```

Comment: Please post the code that is delivered to the browser, not the code that generates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I would say it's because you aren't providing a `value` attribute for the option elements. In browsers conforming to W3C standards, the value of an option with no value attribute is the text of the option. Unfortunately IE 8 and lower didn't follow that particular part of the standard. The simple answer is to put a value in each option, something like:

```
  echo "<option value=". $info['cityname'].">". $info['cityname']."</option>" ;
```